# What does `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq` try to do?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cpu-frequency

On my Ubuntu 16.04, I am trying  to understand a system default file `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq` (see the end of this post for its content.)

Is `"${PM_FUNCTIONS}"` a script, given that it is sourced by `.`?

When I `echo "${PM_FUNCTIONS}"`  in bash, it outputs nothing. Is `PM_FUNCTIONS` defined in another script which calls the script?

Are `savestate`, `state_exists`, and `restorestate` functions defined in `"${PM_FUNCTIONS}"`?

Is `TEMPORARY_CPUFREQ_GOVERNOR"` a variable defined in `"${PM_FUNCTIONS}"`?

What does the script try to do upon `suspend|hibernate` and upon `thaw|resume`?

Thanks.

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                          
# Ensure cpu governor is set to something sane.                                                                                                                                    
# TODO: Which of the cpu governors is still insane?  File bugs against                                                                                                             
#       those that are.                                                                                                                                                            

. "${PM_FUNCTIONS}"

[ -d /sys/devices/system/cpu/ ] || exit $NA

hibernate_cpufreq()
{
  ( cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/
  for x in cpu[0-9]*; do
    # if cpufreq is a symlink, it is handled by another cpu. Skip.                                                                                                                 
    [ -L "$x/cpufreq" ] && continue
    gov="$x/cpufreq/scaling_governor"
    # if we do not have a scaling_governor file, skip.                                                                                                                             
    [ -f "$gov" ] || continue
    # if our temporary governor is not available, skip.                                                                                                                            
    grep -q "$TEMPORARY_CPUFREQ_GOVERNOR" \
            "$x/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors" || continue
    savestate "${x}_governor" < "$gov"
    echo "$TEMPORARY_CPUFREQ_GOVERNOR" > "$gov"
  done )
}

thaw_cpufreq()
{
  ( cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/
  for x in cpu[0-9]*/cpufreq/scaling_governor ; do
    [ -f "$x" ] || continue
    state_exists "${x%%/*}_governor" || continue
    restorestate "${x%%/*}_governor" > "$x"
  done )
}

case "$1" in
  suspend|hibernate)
    hibernate_cpufreq
    ;;
  resume|thaw)
    thaw_cpufreq
    ;;
  *) exit $NA
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

The functions `state_exists`, etc are defined in [/usr/lib/pm-utils/functions](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/pm-utils/tree/pm/functions.in) and `PM_FUNCTIONS` refers to the script [/usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/pm-utils/tree/pm/pm-functions.in). And yes, `TEMPORARY_CPUFREQ_GOVERNOR` is defined in `PM_FUNCTIONS`.

Comment: Thanks. How did you find them out  by just looking at the file system?  Where is `PM_FUNCTIONS` defined? How shall I find out where `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq` and `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_cpu_freq` are called?

Comment: You can find filenames using `find` or `locate` and then search the files using grep. For instance, to search for the variable `TEMPORARY_CPUFREQ_GOVERNOR` you can use the command `grep -ri "TEMPORARY_CPUFREQ_GOVERNOR" /usr/lib/pm-utils`

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering how to find out where `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq `and `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_cpu_freq` are called? Under `/usr/lib/pm-utils/`, I run `grep -R freq .`, and it only return the file `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq`, which is meaningless. I run `grep -R sleep.d .`, and it returns nothing useful either.

Comment: They are hooks that are run in the function `_run_hooks()` from the file `pm-functions`.  Note the part that looks like this: `for base in $(IFS="${oifs}"; for f in "$syshooks/"*[!~] "$phooks/"*[!~]; do [ -O "$f" ] && echo ${f##*/} ; done | $sort | uniq) ;` ... See [How do I run commands on suspend/return from suspend?](https://superuser.com/questions/733333/how-do-i-run-commands-on-suspend-return-from-suspend)

Comment: By the way, to find that, I used `grep` as follows: `grep -ri '\.d' /usr/lib/pm-utils/`, which returned a couple of lines that looked like this: `usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions: local syshooks="${PM_UTILS_ETCDIR}/$1.d"` I searched for ".d" in because since `sleep.d` wasn't showing up explicitly, I figured there was some kind of loop that went through all of the ".d" directories.

Comment: Thanks! [`/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq` doesn't seem to be executed upon resuming from suspension](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435168/why-are-scripts-under-usr-lib-pm-utils-sleep-d-and-etc-pm-sleep-d-not-ex).