# Why are there these differences between suspension by the DEs and by pm-utils?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, power-management, lxde, pm-utils

I found some differences between running `pm-suspend` and 
 clicking "Suspend" menu item in LXDE on Ubuntu 16.04

1. In both cases I can wake up Ubuntu by pushing the power button on my laptop, but in the way by "Suspend" menu item in LXDE, I have to provide my password to unlock the screen, while in the way by `pm-suspend` (and by`pm-hibernate` or `pm-suspend-hybrid`), I don't need to.
2. According to this question [How do I run commands on suspend/return from suspend? | Super User](https://superuser.com/a/733336/9265), scripts under `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/` and `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` are supposed to be executed upon suspension/hibernation and resuming/thawing.  But it is true  only when I run `pm-suspend` (or`pm-hibernate` or `pm-suspend-hybrid`), and [false when I click "Suspend" menu item in LXDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021448/how-shall-i-configure-cpu-frequency-upon-resuming-from-suspension-of-ubuntu/1021499#1021499).

I used to use Gnome, and I remember it was the same as in LXDE, except Gnome might have hibernate option besides suspend.

I wonder why there are the differences between suspension by the DEs and by pm-utils?

Can `pm-suspend` be used in a way so that resume requires password to unlock the screen?

Can "suspend" menu item in LXDE be used in a way so that the scripts in 
`/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/` and `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` are executed upon suspension/hibernation and resuming/thawing?

Thanks.

Comment: Like you mentioned in your comment on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/485056/281844, this might be the difference between `pm-suspend` and `systemctl suspend`... Can you try if when you run `systemctl suspend` everything works as expected? (i.e. screen gets locked and requires password to unlock?) You can inspect the systemd hook directory (`/usr/lib/systemd/sleep/`) to see if it's populated with hooks but even better look if there are any inhibitors in place with [`systemd-inhibit --list`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-inhibit.html) to check.

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger Thanks. I appreciate if you could consider https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485593/why-is-my-script-not-executed-when-waking-up-from-systemd-suspension